# definition of a custom resource in SKUBER

Tags: scala

I don't quite understand how [skuber](https://github.com/doriordan/skuber) creates custom resources. while I get the general idea for "typical" resources with replicas, I don't understand how would I define a resource which spec is a string.

for example, this would be the definition of the resource in YALM (which I can use to create the resource using kubectl)

```
kind: IAMRole
metadata:
  name: 123-role
  namespace: namespace
spec:
  document: |
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::awsbucket"
        }
    }
```

so i tried to create the custom resource in skuber defining the spec as:

```
def iamRoleSpecFor(realm: String): String =
    s"""document: |
          {
              "Version": "2012-10-17",
              "Statement": {
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Action": [
                      "s3:GetObject",
                      "s3:ListBucket"            ],
                  "Resource": [
                      "arn:aws:s3:::bucket1",
                      "arn:aws:s3:::bucket1/*"
                  ]
              }
          }"""
```

and then using said spec in the object definition. but when i try to make the call to k8s, the server responds with HTTP 422

> resource-controller" denied the request: Role missing "document"),None,None,Some(422))

so how should I specify the resource Spec?

anybody here has some extra experience with skuber and would be willing to give me a hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a comprehensive [custom resource test](https://github.com/doriordan/skuber/blob/master/client/src/it/scala/skuber/CustomResourceSpec.scala) 
that demonstrates how to define and use custom resources in skuber, including how to set the spec.

As far as your spec is concerned, in general you just need to define it as a case class together with an implicit Play Json formatter:

```
case class IAMRoleSpec(document: String)
implicit val iamRoleSpecFmt: Format[IAMRoleSpec]
```

You can then use the CustomResource class parameterised with the Spec type, as shown in the test.